# Where is the binary of a ROS package node

Tags: ros, rosnode, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing ROS, I can use "rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key". Where can I find the binary corresponding to the node turtle_teleop_key?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287485/where-is-the-binary-of-a-ros-package-node/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For `turtlesim` specifically: see #q214020.

In general: see #q209051 and in short: in the `lib/` sub dir of the [devel](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Development_.28Devel.29_Space) or [install](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Install_Space) spaces (`/opt/ros/$distro` is essentially an install space).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2